# Unable to burn attribute values from vector shapefile onto raster using gdal.RasterizeLayer

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-rasterize

I am trying to rasterize a shapefile but keep getting errors regarding either my disk space or something about overwriting existing tiff files. The field is an integer in the shapefile. Currently, I'm getting the error: `hDstDS != NULL` but options that imply creating a new dataset have been set.

Below is the code I am working on:

```
fn_vec = 'C:/Users/Name/OneDrive/Documents/Project/clipped2.shp' #path to vector shapefile
output_raster=os.getcwd()+'/rasterize.tif'
vec_ds = ogr.Open(fn_vec) #this is the vector dataset opened
lyr = vec_ds.GetLayer()
source_srs=lyr.GetSpatialRef()
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax =lyr.GetExtent()
pixel_size=5000

#%%create destination data source
x_res = int((xmax - xmin) / pixel_size)
y_res = int((ymax - ymin) / pixel_size)
target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(output_raster, x_res, y_res, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)

#%%
NoData_value=0
target_ds.SetGeoTransform((xmin, pixel_size, 0, ymax, 0, -pixel_size))
band = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
band.SetNoDataValue(NoData_value)
target_ds.SetProjection(source_srs.ExportToWkt())

#%%
target_ds = gdal.Rasterize(target_ds, fn_vec, xRes=pixel_size, yRes=pixel_size, 
                    attribute='CT',outputBounds=[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax], 
                    outputType=gdal.GDT_Byte)
#target_ds.FlushCache()
#del target_ds
ds=None
```

Comment: Is the pixel size really 5km? That seems very coarse. Is your data in a projected CRS? if it's geographical you would be creating a raster with 0 rows and columns (int() truncates). The only concern I have with your code is that you're assigning the return value from Rasterize (CPL_ERR I think) to your target ds, have a look at the examples on https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/101827/gdal.RasterizeLayer and you will see that the return value isn't collected in these examples.